# Is there a performance benefit to explicitly using System.IO instead of importing it?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB file that imports System.IO, but only uses it is a couple of places.  My co-workers and I were wondering if there is a small performance boost if we just use System.IO explicitly were we need it (IE., System.IO.MemoryStream) instead of importing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. There's no difference.  The compiler produces exactly the same IL in either case.

You can prove it by compiling it both ways, and then using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble the assembly and observe the IL produced.

Answer (score 3):

Robert is exactly correct.  I'll add that the purpose of importing namespaces (VB.NET is `Imports`; C# is `using`) is to avoid having to type the fully-qualified name of every class that you intend to consume.  The compiled IL code still uses the fully qualified name, so importing the namespace is just there to simplify some of your work as a developer.

One drawback with importing namespaces is that if someone gives you code to use, but doesn't share with you the top of their code file with the namespace imports, you have to figure out for yourself what namespace to add.

Comment: Good point about sharing code. I see that happen all the time (especially on this site), and then you have to go Google all the types to figure out what namespace they're in.